# Getting array elements with a parent and child logic

Tags: java

I have two arrays named parent and child like this

```
Child [] = {1,5,6,7}
```

and

```
Parent [] = {2,1,5,8}
```

When i enter a parent element it should give the child element. in the same way it should give the child's child element.

for example:

1. if i given 2 as a input. then the output will be 1,5,6
2. if i given 1 as a input. then the output will be 5,6
3. if i given 5 as a input. then the output will be 6
4. if i given 8 as a input. then the output will be 7

i tried it giving a continuos loop.

```
//final code
package parentchild;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class ParentChild {
    static int [] child = {1,5,6,7};
    static int [] parent = {2,1,5,8};

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("enter:");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int x = sc.nextInt();

        int len = parent.length-1;

        while(x!= parent[len])
        {
          for(int i=0;i<=3;i++)
          {
              if(x==parent[i])
              {
                 System.out.println(child[i]);
              }

              x = child[i];
          }   
          return;
    }

       while(x== parent[len])
       {
           System.out.println(child[len]);
           return;
       }





    }
}
```

Comment: _i tried it giving a continuos loop_ Show the code which you have tried

Comment: I don't get it.. What should happen if you enter 8?

Comment: it makes no sense, i couldn't find the logic behind this child and parent array... please give some more example and post the codes you have done

Comment: when i enter parent element it should display the child element and also its should display the child element @fmodos

Comment: the value which is displayed to X and again I have to run the loop to get the child's child....eg: (x = 2 and child of 2 is 1) and then (x= 1 and chils of 1 is 5) and again (x = 5 ... child of 5 is 6)...then loop should stop

Comment: @user1673787, debug this code using IDE, step by step and watch the values of variables, you will get catch where logic is getting flawed.

Comment: @PradeepSimha You get what my problem is ? okay i am starting from scratch again

Comment: @user1673787, in your code you don't have ending condition of loop, that's why it is going to infinate loop, debugging will resolve this.

Comment: you described the solution in your comment, just review a little the code and do some test that you will get it to work

Comment: problem solved but i have to improve this code i am placing my final code

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm seems to work but it is a little complex and has more iterations, as you solved it here is an improved code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("enter:");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int x = sc.nextInt();

        while (true) {
            boolean found = false;
            for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
                if (x == parent[i]) {
                                    x = child[i];
                    System.out.println(child[i]);
                                    //indicate that found  a parent 
                    found = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            // stop the program, if no parent was found
            if (!found) {
                return;
            }
        }
    }
```